# Package babel Error: Unknow option `brazilian'

Tags: errors, texlive, babel

When trying to compile any document containing the line:

```
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
```

I get the following error:

```
! Package babel Error: Unknow option `brazilian'. Either you misspelled it
(babel)                or the language definition file brazilian.ldf was not fo
und.
```

Additional info:

- I get an analagous error when replacing `brazilian` by anything other than `english`.
- I'm running texlive on Windows, so my way of managing packages is through `tlmgr`
- Tried to uninstall and reinstall babel package and got nothing.
- I sense something is wrong since babel is looking for the file "brazilian.ldf" but this is my output to `tlmgr search --global --file "brazilian"`:

```
tlmgr.pl: package repository http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
biblatex:
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/brazilian.lbx
biblatex-apa:
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/brazilian-apa.lbx
dvdcoll:
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/dvdcoll/dcl/brazilian.dcl
minitoc:
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/minitoc/brazilian.mld
```

So, no brazilian.ldf here...

**UPDATE:**

Looking at the comments and searching for `portuges.ldf` file, the following package install command solved the problem here:

```
tlmgr install babel-portuges
```

*(ps: had to remove old .aux files)*

Comment: Use `brazil` instead.

Comment: What engine are you using to compile with? (pdfLaTeX? LuaLaTeX?) The `brazilian` option is a synonym of `portuges` which is why you won't find a `brazilian.ldf`.

Comment: I used this command to install babel-portugues: sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-portuguese

Answer (score 14):

If you don't have the language installed you can do it installing `texlive-lang-portuguese`.

Then the `brazilian` option should work.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how exactly can I install it? It's through tlmgr (it says there is no such package)?

Comment: @BabelError: That's probably a debian/ubuntu package.

Answer (score 11):

If you look into `babel.sty` (version 2013/05/16 v3.9f), you will see the option declaration for `brazilian`:

```
\DeclareOption{brazil}{\bbl@load@language{portuges}}
\DeclareOption{brazilian}{\bbl@load@language{portuges}}
```

Thus the basic language definition file is `portuges.ldf`.
It is often the case that a language can support several dialects and aliases.

The file `portuges.ldf` is part of package `babel-portuges` in TeX Live 2013.
From `tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb` (TeX Live Package DataBase):

```
name babel-portuges
category Package
revision 30284
docfiles size=36
 texmf-dist/doc/generic/babel-portuges/portuges.pdf
srcfiles size=7
 texmf-dist/source/generic/babel-portuges/portuges.dtx
 texmf-dist/source/generic/babel-portuges/portuges.ins
runfiles size=2
 texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-portuges/portuges.ldf
```

As option `brazilian` is known to `babel` (see the option declaration above), the file `portuges.ldf` is very likely not installed. After installing `babel-portuges` with `tlmgr` the problem should be solved.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}`, use `\usepackage[brazil]{babel}`. It should work.

According to the documentation, **brazilian** should work as well as **brazil**, but it isn't. Perhaps **brazilian** was removed (no longer in use) but the documentation wasn't updated. The weird thing is that taking a fast look at the code, **brazilian** is there! Maybe it's a bug. Not sure! I am using the latest package update until this post.

Please leave a feedback if it worked or not. Don't forget to ensure *Babel* package is properly installed on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
sudo dnf texlive-babel brazil
```

I'm using fedora btw.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately, this isn’t applicable to the vast majority of TeX installations. An answer about how to install the required package on other systems would be a great improvement.